# Regex problems with equal sign?

Tags: c#, regex

In C# I'm trying to validate a string that looks like:

`I@paramname='test'`

or

`O@paramname=2827`

Here is my code:

```
 string t1 = "I@parameter='test'";

 string r = @"^([Ii]|[Oo])@\w=\w";

 var re = new Regex(r);
```

If I take the "=\w" off the end or variable r I get True.  If I add an "=\w" after the \w it's False.  I want the characters between @ and = to be able to be any alphanumeric value.  Anything after the = sign can have alphanumeric and ' (single quotes).  What am I doing wrong here.  I very rarely have used regular expressions and normally can find example, this is custom format though and even with cheatsheets I'm having issues.

Comment: `'` is not a "word character" so it will not match `\w`. Compare the results when using `"I@parameter=test"` as input.

Comment: Maybe something like this (untested): `([IiOo])@\w+=[\w']+`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^([Ii]|[Oo])@\w+=(?<q>'?)[\w\d]+\k<q>$
```

Regular expression:

```
^               start of line
 ([Ii]|[Oo])    either (I or i) or (O or o)
 \w+            1 or more word characters
   =            equals sign
   (?<q>'?)     capture 0 or 1 quotes in named group q
   [\w\d]+      1 or more word or digit characters
   \k<q>        repeat of what was captured in named group q
$               end of line
```

Comment: Just realized that for strings that start with O I don't need an equal sign or value.  Is there a way to make that "optional"?

Answer (score 2):

use `\w+` instead of `\w` to one character or more. Or `\w*` to get zero or more:

Try this: [Live demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/nIczLfRzybbCWzIA)

```
^([Ii]|[Oo])@\w+=\'*\w+\'*
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are being a bit more strict with using `paramname`:

```
^([Ii]|[Oo])@paramname=[']?[\w]+[']?
```

[Here is a demo](http://regexr.com?37p1p)

Comment: paramname can't be hardcoded I just used that as an example.  It's actually used in a generic function to call a stored procedure and that will be the name of the stored procedure parameter.

Comment: I/O (input/output) and then the value after the equal sign.

Comment: So now you got me thinking... i can't pass a value to an OUT stored procedure parameter. I will have to modify it so on OUT it ignores anything after equal sign.  Thanks for making gears in my head start moving :)

Comment: @RandyR, I'm not sure what I did, but you're welcome. And I saw just after I posted that you wanted to change "paramname" at will, but I left my answer because the technique for the rest is different that the others, more variety.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
Regex rx = new Regex( @"^([IO])@(\w+)=(.*)$" , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase ) ;
```

- Match group 1 will give you the value of I or O (the parameter direction?)
- Match group 2 will give you the name of the parameter
- Match group 3 will give you the value of the parameter

You could be stricter about the 3rd group and match it as

```
(([^']+)|('(('')|([^']+))*'))
```

The first alternative matches 1 or more non quoted character; the second alternative match a quoted string literal with any internal (embedded) quotes escape by doubling them, so it would match things like

- `''` (the empty string
- `'foo bar'`
- `'That''s All, Folks!'`